# How portable is the use of getch outside curses mode?

Tags: c, ncurses, portability, curses

I'm working on a terminal program to recognize individual key presses, including keypad keys, but I'd rather not do it in curses/program mode if possible.  Rather than reinvent the wheel using terminfo and some sort of mapping or tree structure for fast keypad key matching, I figured I might just leverage curses and use `tcgetattr()` and `tcsetattr()` to do what I want outside curses mode while still using curses I/O functions to do the translation of keypad keys for me.  Much to my surprise, this works (Linux, ncurses 6.1.20180127):

```
/**
 * Most error checking elided for brevity.
 */
#include <stdio.h>     // printf
#include <string.h>    // memcpy

#include <curses.h>
#include <termios.h>   // tcgetattr, tcsetattr

int main(void)
{
    struct termios curr, new_shell_mode;
    int c, fd;
    SCREEN *sp;
    FILE *ttyf;

    /*
     * Initialize desired abilities in curses.
     * This unfortunately clears the screen, so
     * a refresh() is required, followed by
     * endwin().
     */
    ttyf = fopen("/dev/tty", "r+b");
    fd = fileno(ttyf);
    sp = newterm(NULL, ttyf, ttyf);
    raw();
    noecho();
    nonl();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    refresh();
    // Save the current curses mode TTY attributes for later use.
    tcgetattr(fd, &curr);
    endwin();

    /*
     * Set the shell/non-curses mode TTY attributes to
     * match those of program/curses mode (3 attempts).
     */
    memcpy(&new_shell_mode, &curr, sizeof curr);
    for (c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
        tcsetattr(fd, TCSADRAIN, &new_shell_mode);
        tcgetattr(fd, &curr);
        if (0 == memcmp(&new_shell_mode, &curr, sizeof curr))
            break;
    }
    // If new shell mode could fully be set, get a key press.
    if (c != 3)
        c = getch();
    reset_shell_mode();
    delscreen(sp);
    fclose(ttyf);
    printf("%02X\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

However, given that I've exited curses mode, is it actually safe/portable to still use `getch()` in the manner shown?

Or do I need to take the more difficult path of using `setupterm()` to load the terminfo DB and loop through the `strnames` array, calling `tigetstr()` for each, plus set my own termios flags manually and deal with reading the keypress myself?

Nothing in the XSI Curses spec seems to forbid this, provided `stdscr` remains valid, which seems to be either until the program exits or `delwin()` is called, I can continue using it, and since `stdscr` is connected to my `ttyf` file, which is the terminal, I can use it to get a keypress without resorting to handling everything myself.

Comment: Minor: Note rather than `memcpy(&new_shell_mode, &curr, sizeof curr);`, code could use `new_shell_mode = curr;`

Comment: @chux I didn't even think about that since I'm often working with opaque/implementation-defined pointers. Thank you.

Comment: I definitely wouldn't try this in PDCurses.

Comment: @WilliamMcBrine The code is intended solely for terminal implementations, not GUI implementations. What I'm working on already has a Windows console implementation and cross-platform GUI implementation, so I'm merely extending the functionality to Linux and, hopefully, macOS.

Comment: You don't reinvent the wheel.  That's the way to do it.  Loading your applications with the full curses library only because it's there the only place you have an implementation of `getch(3)` is a common case of bad programming habits.  The curses library is over 1Mb binary code added to your executable, to use only one routine.

Comment: There's no curses routine you can use between `endwin()` and `newterm()`, that includes `getch(3)`.

Comment: @LuisColorado My choices for set-up are: slow init+portable (`setupterm()`, call `tigetstr()` for every string capability listed in the `strnames` array and cache the values), fast init+unportable (`setupterm()`, read terminfo file directly and cache the names and values), or fast init+portable (use curses). For reading input in the cases where a curses library isn't used at all, I can use termios to set the desired attributes and figure out how to use `VMIN` and `VTIME` to mimic the behavior of `getch()` (on a slow remote connection too). Or I could just use `getch()` :-\

Comment: @ChronoKitsune, to mimic the behaviour of `getch()` I can tell you, just set `VMIN` to `1` and `VTIME` to 0.  Then you'll get the input char by char and without any timeout between characters (blocking read).

Comment: @LuisColorado Yes, I understand that bit. The issue I was having with that was the fact that doing _only_ that would lead to bytes being sent in two separate reads over SSH and sometimes even multiple [partial or full] key presses being in the same read, resulting in things like the F12 key generating the CSI or SS3 sequence on the first read and the next read containing the rest of the control/shift sequence. `getch()` didn't have this problem, so I figured I'd just use it.

Comment: Well, I am not sure, but I think the introduction of `VMIN` & `VTIME` was made to cope with this (using a `VTIME` value different than zero allow you to receive such escape sequences in one `read(2)` call) and mice devices... But if you use a value of `VTIME` different than zero, then you had better to configure a larger amount for `VMIN` so you can read a complete escape in just one read.  Anyway, you have to detect the `<esc>` character and identify correctly the actual character, and that is solved in a terminal independent way.  If you want such functionality, you had better to use curses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialized curses using **`newterm`**, and it doesn't ***matter*** that you called **`endwin`**: curses will resume full-screen mode if it does a **`refresh`** as a side-effect of calling **`getch`**.

That's not just ncurses, but any curses implementation (except for long-obsolete BSD versions from the 1980s).  [X/Open Curses](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/getch.html) notes

> If the current or specified window is not a pad, and it has been moved or modified since the last refresh operation, then it will be refreshed before another character is read.

In your example, nothing was "moved or modified".  But `getch` checks.  (There's probably nothing to be gained by the **`endwin`**/termios stuff, since **`newterm`** doesn't do a clear-screen until the first **`refresh`**).

Comment: This was tremendously helpful. Removing the termios stuff results in the same behavior, which is obviously a good thing. However, the manual `refresh()` to trigger the clear-screen that `newterm()` requires and the following `endwin()` to exit curses are both required, else `getch()` will cause the refresh. I believe that's consistent with what you have just stated, but I could be wrong.

Comment: hmm - the `keypad` function does rely upon the `refresh`, since it switches the terminal into application mode more often than not.

Comment: That makes sense, though it still seems to require the `refresh()` anyway, even if all I have is `newterm(...); endwin(); getch(); if (!isendwin()) endwin(); else reset_shell_mode();` In any case, the manual `refresh()` and single `endwin()` works. Thanks!